# How to populate data to multiple user by single request to the host

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, model-view-controller

we are working on a complex Web application project, we have one host which is giving the Live data with certain ratio. problem is we are restricted to make only one call for one action, as the data is live so we cannot waste time to store data in DB we have to show the data to our users with the same speed we are getting. and we are not allowed to send multiple request to the host for the same action, or from different IP's, so we have to make a service that will work like a hub, get data in one request of a certain action call by Multiple users, and give response to them in same speed we get the response from host.

Comment: How frequent does the data change? How are you expecting the clients to update the data on the screen? Are all the clients expecting to update at the same time or based on a request from the user?

Comment: Have you considered using Signal R? From what I understand your application architecture is a very good candidate for Signal R. Signal R can be used to develop real time web application, more information on signal R can be found in in the MS document [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr]. Please check this link to find a sample Demo [http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/signalr]

Comment: the data Change 20 times in 100ms